# Excel HPageBreaks NOT working, using VBSCript

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to set page breaks after row number 40 but its appearing on row number: 45. The output excel file should be of two pages.

Can someone tell me the mistake which i created. Your Help will be greatly appreciated. (I tried to solve this from last 6 hours but no luck :) )

This code is part of my assignment, so i am trying this without changing the column width.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel,objWorkbook,objSheet,objRange,intPageBreakRow,intRow,i

const xlPageBreakPreview  = &H2

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("B:F")
objRange.WrapText = TRUE

objSheet.Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 1
objSheet.Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = 25
objSheet.Range("C:C").ColumnWidth = 25
objSheet.Range("D:D").ColumnWidth = 45
objSheet.Range("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14
objSheet.Range("F:F").ColumnWidth = 20

objSheet.DisplayAutomaticPageBreaks = False

With objSheet.PageSetup
 .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
 .FitToPagesTall = 2
End With
objSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
objSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks  

intPageBreakRow=40
intRow=90

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Page1 This is the text that we want to wrap in column A."
objExcel.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Page1 This is the text that we want to wrap in column B."
objExcel.Cells(3, 3).Value = "Page1 This is the text that we want to wrap in column C."
objExcel.Cells(5, 5).Value = "Page1 This is the text that we want to wrap in column E."
objExcel.Cells(6, 6).Value = "Page1 This is the text that we want to wrap in column F."

For i=2 To intPageBreakRow
    objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Page1 This is the text that we want to wrap in column D."
Next

objSheet.Range("F72").Value = "Page2 Some text aligned to the center"
objSheet.Range("F72").WrapText = True

For i=intPageBreakRow+1 To intRow
    objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Page2 This is the text that we want to wrap in column D."
Next

'objExcel.Range("A1: F"&intRow).Select  
objExcel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea="A1: F"&intRow
objSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

'objExcel.Rows(intPageBreakRow+1).Select        
objSheet.HPageBreaks.Add objSheet.Rows(intPageBreakRow+1)

objExcel.ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview                                     
objExcel.Rows.AutoFit
```

Comment: Step through your code (using F8) one line at a time, keeping an eye on important values by hovering your mouse over variables on each line stepped through.  The problem should become more clear.  More detail on this and other VBA Debugging tips from the amazing Chip Pearson **[located here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)**.

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for the response, Here I cleared all default page breaks to set new pagebreaks. (The output excel sheet should be of two pages).  but always the page breaks appearing on row number 45 even though i mentioned as 40 (variable intPageBreakRow =40).